# Anaconda matplotlib theme / styling / colorcyle

Tags: matplotlib, styles, themes, anaconda

Does anyone know what a default Anaconda install does to change Matplotlib styling?

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
pl.figure()
pl.xlabel('X label')
pl.ylabel('Y label')
pl.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
pl.plot([1,2,3], [6,5,4])
pl.show()
```

The above code creates a blue and a green line on default matplotlib, but blue and orange when run in Anaconda. The axis labels have also changed from a serif (default) to a sans-serif font (Anaconda).

Is this a matplotlib theme? Custom or available from (free) sources? Is it anaconda itself or some package included in it?

Any hints/answers are much appreciated

-- Update --

I found two matplotlibrc files in the anaconda directory, both simply set a backend and had all other lines commented out.

Comment: Look for `matplotlibrc` file according to this guide https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

Comment: Thanks! But I can't find any active lines relating to styling/themes in the anaconda supplied `matplotlibrc` files (unless I'm looking at the wrong ones?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with anaconda. You most likely have two different versions of matplotlib installed and the one that anaconda uses is the newer one of them.

The default style of matplotlib changed between versions 1.5 and 2.0. See [Changes to the default style](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0rc2/users/dflt_style_changes.html).

To revert to the classic style (the one used in version 1.5), you may use

```
plt.style.use("classic")
```

For an overview of all available styles, see the [style_sheets_reference for 2.0.0](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html).

You may create your own stylesheets as detailed in the [Customizing](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) article.

Comment: Thanks! So Anaconda comes with matplotlib 2.0 then, that's the difference! (How many versions I had installed before anaconda really doesn't matter though, anaconda installs its own version, that's the point!)